# how to read a csv file from the Internal storage

Tags: android, csv

Here's my code. I create a folder named “raw” inside the “res” folder and put the CSV file in it. My program reads the csv from the
folder "raw" and it works. Now I want to do the same but reading the
csv file from the internal storage. I can't find code that works.
Any ideas?

I've already tried these ones:

- `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`
- `Environment.getDataDirectory()`
- `Environment.getRootDirectory()`

These access the internal memory but you can't see these folders if you
navigate form your device, it's a file path only accessible from the app.
I need to be able to access any folder from the device to read the CSV
file. And I don't want to use SDC card to read that external memory.

Thanks!

```
dato2 = codigo.getText().toString();  
String linea;
boolean encontrado=false;
InputStream archivo=this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(archivo));

if(archivo!=null)
{

    while(( linea=reader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        String pro=linea.split(";")[0];
        String pre=linea.split(";")[1];
        String cod=linea.split(";")[2];
        if(dato2.equals(cod))
        {

            Producto proproducto = new Producto(pro, pre, cod);
            listaProductos.add(proproducto);       
            encontrado=true;
        }

    }

    if(encontrado==false)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No se encontro",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
archivo.close();
```

Comment: Well where did you put your file? How did you do that? Use the same path. And getExternalStorageDirectory is a pretty normal path if it is not Android Q.

Comment: I've put it in many folders that can be navegated from the phone. /Internal Memory/anyfolder
I did it by cable, accessed the intermal memory and pasted the file there.
Problem with getExternalStorageDirectory is that it seems you can't access this path if you are not root user on the phone. I've also read in some forums that it works in certains phones only

Comment: No. No root user. I told you it was a quite normal path and that is what it id. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> BufferReader

with

> Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory

like the following. It returns List of String but you can change it to fit your needs. Asset folder would be appropriate to store such files.

```
private List<String> getStringFromExtraFile(String fileName){
        List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        File sdCardFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdCardFile, fileName);
        try{
            if(file.exists())
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String returned;

            while((returned = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                resultList.add(returned);
            }
             bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resultList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a file from raw directory, need to follow in this manner.

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier("FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION",
            "raw", getPackageName()));
```

and use this `implementation com.opencsv:opencsv:4.6'` to read the csv file content.

Comment: It seems this code is similiar to the one I've used. I don't have problems to get the file from "raw" android project resource folder. What I need is to read it from the phone internal memory. I want to be able to specify the path. and this path must be public, any other app can access this path. I need to plug in my phone paste a file in any folder of the internal memory. And the app I'm building needs to be able to access this file path. 
getExternalStorageDirectory leads you to "Storage/emulated/" and you can only see it or navigate it from your phone if you are root user